# MVC3 Html.BeginForm inside a WebGrid column?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I had a somewhat crazy idea earlier tonight, and got 3/4 of the way done implementing it and have run in to a weird problem..  I wanted to automatically generate an index of all methods on a controller than return an ActionResult, as well as a simple form for each to sumbmit their valid data..  Seemed like a pretty simple thing to do via reflection:

Quickie ViewModel to hold each reflected action:

```cs
public class ReflectedAction
{
    public ReflectedAction(MethodInfo methodInfo, string controllerName)
    {
        this.ActionName = methodInfo.Name;
        this.ControllerName = controllerName;
        this.Parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters().Select(p => p.Name);
    }

    public string ControllerName { get; set; }

    public string ActionName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

Action to reflect all the actions on the current controller:

```cs
public virtual ActionResult AutoIndex()
{
    Type controllerType = this.ControllerContext.Controller.GetType();
    string controllerName = controllerType.Name.Replace("Controller", string.Empty);

    var methods = this.ControllerContext.Controller.GetType().GetMethods().Where(
            m => m.ReturnType.Name.Contains("ActionResult"));

    var model = methods.Select(m => new ReflectedAction(m, controllerName));

    return View(model);
}
```

Inside the view, I just wanted to use a simple WebGrid to render out each action as a row, with the first column being the name of the action, and the second column being a mini-form, with the ability to fill out any fields that the action has (I tried doing it as a helper, or inline in the grid format, latter is include here:

```
@using TfsMvc.Controllers
@model IEnumerable<TestController.ReflectedAction>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AutoIndex";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>AutoIndex</h2>

@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(
        source: Model,
        ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid",
        defaultSort: "ActionName",
        canPage: false);
}

<div id="grid">
    @grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "grid",
    headerStyle: "head",
    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("ActionName"),
        grid.Column(format: (action) =>
            {
                using (Html.BeginForm((string)action.ActionName, (string)action.ControllerName, FormMethod.Get))
                {
                    string htmlString = string.Empty;

                    foreach (string parameter in action.Parameters)
                    {
                        htmlString = "<span>" + Html.Label(parameter) + Html.TextBox(parameter) + "</span>";
                    }

                    htmlString += "<input type=\"submit\" />";

                    return new HtmlString(htmlString);
                }
            }))
        )
</div>
```

The grid *appears* to render correctly, but the weird part is that all the form html tags render outside the grid, but the controls render inside the grid:

```html
<div id="grid">
    <form action="/Test/CloneTestPlan" method="get"></form>
    <form action="/Test/ConfigureTestPlan" method="get"></form>
    <form action="/Test/EnvConfig" method="get"></form>
    <form action="/Test/FixTestLink" method="get"></form>

    <!-- ton of other actions snipped-->

    <table class="grid">
        <thead>
            <tr class="head"><th scope="col"><a href="#" onclick="$(&#39;#grid&#39;).load(&#39;/Test/SecretIndex?sort=ActionName&amp;sortdir=DESC&amp;__=634581349851993336 #grid&#39;);">ActionName</a></th><th scope="col"></th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>CloneTestPlan</td><td><span><label for="subid">subid</label><input id="subid" name="subid" type="text" value="" /></span><input type="submit" /></td></tr>
            <tr class="alt"><td>ConfigureTestPlan</td><td><span><label for="apply">apply</label><input id="apply" name="apply" type="text" value="" /></span><input type="submit" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>EnvConfig</td><td><span><label for="create">create</label><input id="create" name="create" type="text" value="" /></span><input type="submit" /></td></tr>
            <tr class="alt"><td>FixTestLink</td><td><span><label for="commit">commit</label><input id="commit" name="commit" type="text" value="" /></span><input type="submit" /></td></tr>

            <!-- ton of other actions snipped-->

        </tbody></table>
</div>
```

As you can see, the  tags render *outside* of the table!  Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?  Or can you just not *do* BeginForm inside a Webgrid?  Any better approach for making a bunch of individual forms?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is really interesting.  What do you do with this?  Do you use it to demonstrate the functionality to your dev team?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, didn't see you'd added a comment.  It's actually mainly me being lazy and not manually making a static index.  :)  I had a large number of actions I'd made that I couldn't necessarily remember the name of, or the exact parameters they needed.  They were generally sanely named, so I could usually guess...but having an autogenerated index that showed them all was much cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

Try rendering the `<form>` yourself without using the helper.

It looks like the lambdas are executed inside helper before it spits out the content, which causes the `BeginForm` to render to output instantly.

Comment: Aha!  That'd at least explain the bizarre behavior!  Rendering <form> by hand does *does* work, but it just feels dirty and means that I have to worry about properly rendering the path by hand too.  

I'd really like to have some sort of cleaner fashion to do this..  Any idea if there's a way to force the helper to execute within the lambda with the timing that I'm expecting?  This seems like a bug within MVC, if not..

Comment: You can still use `UrlHelper` to render the url. You can also try to call `Html.BeginForm` and `Html.EndForm` without using `using` directive. Or come up with own extension methods.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it will help in your case, but I had similar problem and what I did was:

1. Create partial with following code

   ```
   @using(Html.BeginForm()){
       //some code
   }
   ```
2. In place where problem occurred, call this partial, so in your case it would be something like:

   ```
   grid.Column(format: (action) =>
   {
       Html.Partial("SomePartial")
   })
   ```

PS: The place where I called Partial was different so I'm not sure if above will work.